# How to execute code before Nuxt initializes the state store?

Tags: nuxt.js, decorator, reflect-metadata

I'm trying to load the `reflect-metadata` polyfill so I can use Inversify with a Nuxt app, but I can't manage to load it early enough to be able to use decorators in Vuex modules. (I tried doing this in a plugin, but plugins seem to be loaded after the initialization process.)

Is it possible to hook into the initialization process *before* Nuxt loads the store modules - or anything else?